# How to not store attachment content using Elastica

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

When I have mapping configured something like this:

```
$mapping = new Mapping(…);
$mapping->setProperties([
  …
  'my_attachments' => [ 'type' => 'attachment', 'include_in_all' => true ]
]);
```

It is storing base64 encoded content of the file and increasing index to the ridiculous size. How can I make sure that attachments do get indexed and searchable, but don't store their encoded content in the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to set `_source` to exclude `my_attachments` value:

```
$mapping = new Mapping(…);
$mapping->setProperties([
  …
  'my_attachments' => [ 'type' => 'attachment', 'include_in_all' => true ]
]);
$mapping->setSource([ 'excludes' => 'my_attachments' ]);
```

After implementing this and rebuilding our test index, size dropped from 1.9GB to 89MB.